# Describe table structure using Native SQL in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I am using `h2` in-memory database tables for my JPA rough works. Now I want to view the structure of the table created. So I just written a simple code like

```
Query query1 = entityManager.createNativeQuery("show columns from Mobile");
```

No idea how to print this result set.

Doing like this

```
System.out.println(query1.getFirstResult());
```

is not giving expected output.

Is there any way see table structure generated in `in-memory` database or is there any way to print the data in a meaningful way(like the output what we get while executing `desc tablename`)?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is:

```
Query query1 = em.createNativeQuery("show columns from Mobile");
List<Object[]> results = query1.getResultList();
for (Object[] obj : results) {
    System.out.println("field: " + obj[0]);
    System.out.println("\ttype: " + obj[1]);
    System.out.println("\tnullable: " + obj[2]);
    System.out.println("\tkey: " + obj[3]);
    System.out.println("\tdefault: " + obj[4]);
}
```

I would advise you to take a look at @SqlResultSetMapping though to make this query typesafe.

Answer (score -1):

```
Query query1 = em.createNativeQuery("show columns from Mobile");
List<Object[]> results = query1.getResultList();
for (Object[] obj : results) {
    System.out.println("field: " + obj[0]);
    System.out.println("\ttype: " + obj[1]);
    System.out.println("\tnullable: " + obj[2]);
    System.out.println("\tkey: " + obj[3]);
    System.out.println("\tdefault: " + obj[4]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Surya, but what is value it is adding having @Terrence Curran answer in hand